# Are there performance issues with FKs on different schemas?

Tags: oracle, performance, database-design, foreign-key, referential-integrity

In order to perform functional decomposition of a "big blob" of a database the first step we wanted to take is to separate different modules of the database into separate schemas on the same database instance. We think we want to divide the single schema (180 tables) into probably 8 schemas. Over time each table will be moved to the right schema "where it belongs".

Are there any performance implications we should be aware of, related to foreign keys "crossing" schemas?

We are planning to run the entire database within the same instance/database; we only want to segregate by schemas at this point in time.

Comment: If you set up roles correctly, and views on the tables correctly, you would be able to have all the schemas be able to see the (appropriate) tables in other schemas, and the application role(s) would be able to only see the appropriate schema(s)

Comment: Why would you expect performance issues?  At the i/o level, it's all just data on a disk.  The mechanism of looking it up, locating it, reading it, is all the same.  Schemas are just name spaces - an abstraction.  They are used for organization and administration, not performance.

Comment: @EdStevens Thank you. It's probably just paranoia; the app is currently suffering from significant performance issues (unrelated to FKs, of course) and the subject is sensitive to the clients. I just wanted to cover my back side.

Comment: I don't think 180 tables is that many for one schema. Multi-schema-schemas have been nothing but a huge PITA in my experience even though they doubtless look good in PowerPoint. Deployment scripts will be massively more complicated, circular dependencies will arise, stacks of grants and synonyms will be needed, stored PL/SQL will be duplicated, and all for what?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson "...and all for what?" -- Sigh. Management is asking us to implement "functional decomposition". This means that not only the database will be divided, but the code as well; in the end each piece of code is supposed to never access another database but its own. All inter-database logic should be managed using web services calls, "alla Amazon". Time will tell if this is gonna work or will end up as a big blunder.

Comment: @JoeDiNottra I feel your pain. On one project, it was decreed that customer-identifying information must be held in a separate schema. As a result, tables were split vertically with customer-identifying columns in a separate schema and all queries needing to join them every time, at great cost to performance and zero benefit to customer privacy. By the way, do they really say *database* when they mean *schema*? Alarm bells...